# Missing Referenced Components during Build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-mobile, nuget

Problem Solvers:

I am working a Windows Phone 8 Application. I am just introduced into this product but the project has reached some level. I pulled the codes to my computer and when I tried building the App, I am getting "The Referenced Component 'xxxxxxxxxx' could not be found." (Snips shown below).

[image: The Error Window][image: Solution Explorer Window]

Comment: Try removing and re-adding those all references.

Comment: I just did that... No change.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an algorithm:

- If you just joined a project and cannot build a project: `GOTO A`
- If you want to fix it yourself:

  - Do you use NuGet, if not mention this to your other fellow devs. It's a good idea to pick up. NuGet will re-download binaries from central repository(ies) when you rebuild a project
  - Open project file in notepad (.csproj) and look where the references point to. It's likely they point to some `/bin` or `/obj` folder which developers shouldn't commit and didn't commit. Get the right binaries from other developers or elsewhere, create a folder, like `libs` in your solution, put the binaries there and reference from VS these binaries. Ensure that the `libs` folder is committed to source control
- Start using build server to catch this sort of trouble

**== `A` ==**

Poke your fellow developers (other project committers) to fix the references and commit to source control, so  that you can pick them up

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my Active Solution Platform. The references or project were for "x86" platform while I was trying to build with "Any CPU" platform.